# Have a webpage size grow with an expanding HTML textarea

Tags: html, textarea, web

I've seen it on several websites and was wondering if it something that is build in to HTML/DOM or that would have to use JavaScript.

I have a re sizable textarea, but I want the webpage to grow as the user grows the text area. Right now, if they expand horizontally, they can only expand the size of the page, then stop, scroll to the right and grow it horizontally a little more.

Is there an easy way to allow the page to expand with the textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jquery it is as simple as:

```
$("textarea").resizable({
resize: function() {
    $("body").css('width',YOUR_UPDATE_CALCULATED_WIDTH+'px');
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't believe i missed jQuery UI's resizable. Thank you so much.